# How to append generated numeric ids to some links

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have generated numeric IDs to apply in list that looks like:

```
var _href = $('li').attr('id', function (i, _) {
    return 'item-' + (i + 1);
});
```

Now I want to put this IDs in some links, here is my code:

```
$("a").attr({
    href: "#item-" + _href
});
```

All I need is a multiple repeated list with id (`li#item-1` , `li#item-2` , ...) and some links with those IDs

But it's not working, the result is: `#item-[object Object`]

Comment: You're getting [object Object] because you're returning list elements

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it **simultaneously** targeting an `<a>` using `.eq(Index)`
(where *Index* is the current LI's Index iteration)

```
var $a = $("a"); // P.S: use some better selector like i.e. $("#menu").find("a");

$('li').attr('id', function (i, _) {
   var id = "item-" + (i+1);            // Prepare the result
   $a.eq(i).attr("href", "#"+ id);      // Assign result with #HASH to Anchors .eq()
   return id;                           // Return result as ID
});
```

http://jsbin.com/joraja/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output

---

https://api.jquery.com/eq/

Comment: great! tnx a lot Roko :)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can try this: [**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hyvnqfu2/1/)

```js
var _href = $('li').attr('id', function (i, _) {
    return 'item-' + (i + 1);
});
$('a').each(function(index){
    var x = $('li')[index];
    $(this).attr('href', '#' + $(x).attr('id'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a>Link 1</a>
<a>Link 2</a>
<a>Link 3</a>
<a>Link 4</a>
<a>Link 5</a>
<ul>
  <li>example 1</li>
  <li>example 2</li>
  <li>example 3</li>
  <li>example 4</li>
  <li>example 5</li>
</ul>
```